# Manually handle Silverlight ToolTip

Tags: silverlight, tooltip

I want to show all the ToolTips on a view as soon as it's opened.  That's fine, I can set the ToolTip.IsOpen properties to true.  That certainly shows the ToolTips, the problem is they all show up at (0, 0).  Apparently the positioning of the ToolTips doesn't happen until its target control is hovered.  Only after hovering are the ToolTips positioned correctly.  Setting focus to all the controls first doesn't help either; the target control *has* to receive the hover event.  I'm assuming the ToolTip hooks into the hover event of its target and positions itself inside this event.  Is there a protected method I can call in a ToolTip subclass or some such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell what I'm asking here is not possible beyond manually doing layout or customizing the source. I implemented a completely custom tooltip instead. *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

```
ToolTipService.SetPlacement(button1,
                            System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Top);
```

[See this MSDN Page to see all the placement options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.placement%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**EDIT**

See this article about [the custom positioning of tooltips](http://silverlighttips.com/post/2009/09/01/Create-a-Tooltip-window-with-smart-positioning.aspx). It refers to a project on codeplex that contains the code: [SmartToolTips](http://smarttooltip.codeplex.com/)

Comment: This isn't about the PositionMode property. I'm asking about how to force SL to position the tip w/o first hovering the target control. E.g. if you never hover the control then do (TTS.GetToolTip(button1) as ToolTip).IsOpen = true it'll appear at (0, 0) of the RootVisual. I haven't tested what you suggest but I doubt it helps my case.